# Ubuntu Live-CD can't detect my HDD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, sata

I have been struggling to install Ubuntu on my laptop, I want to make a dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu, but I just can't install it. Already changed my BIOS to AHCI and UEFI, but had no effects so far.

During the installation processes, I´m not even given option to install alongside Windows. After setting language and Internet connection it jumps directly to this screen.

[image: Ubuntu-Install]

It is also very strange because I can find it when using `sudo lshw -class storage -class disk`. What should be my next steps?

Just to help you guys this is the data from GParted:

[image: GParted_Partions]

```
    *-storage               
   description: SATA controller
   product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
   resources: irq:26 ioport:5088(size=8) ioport:5094(size=4) ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5090(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:c3617000-c36177ff
    *-scsi:0
   physical id: 1
   logical name: scsi0
   capabilities: emulated
 *-disk
      description: ATA Disk
      product: WDC WD7500BPKT-7
      vendor: Western Digital
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/sda
      version: 1A01
      serial: WD-WXA1A9147643
      size: 698GiB (750GB)
      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
      configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096 signature=dd6865b6
    *-scsi:1
   physical id: 2
   logical name: scsi1
   capabilities: emulated
 *-disk
      description: ATA Disk
      product: SAMSUNG SSD PM83
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/sdb
      version: 2D1Q
      serial: S0XLNEAC403642
      size: 29GiB (32GB)
      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
      configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=17fdf2ea
    *-scsi:2
   physical id: 3
   logical name: scsi2
   capabilities: emulated
 *-cdrom
      description: DVD-RAM writer
      product: DVD+-RW DS-8A8SH
      vendor: PLDS
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
      logical name: /dev/sr0
      logical name: /cdrom
      version: KD11
      capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
      configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime state=mounted status=ready
    *-medium
         physical id: 0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /cdrom
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime signature=6a6216fc state=mounted
```

Comment: Thanks, Rod Smith! Gonna check that thread, hopefully it will work.

Comment: Oh well!! The only thing is that their solution implies in totally destroying my windows partitions and I really don´t want to do this. My objective is to set a dual-boot.

Comment: My own answer to that question does *not* involve destroying your data.

Comment: @Rod Smith , You were right using [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) did fix my problem! Thank you very much ! Right now I have Ubuntu installed and running without any problems.
I'm leaving a link from my post from Ubuntu Forum, were I will explain step by step how I managed to fix it. [Live-CD won´t detect my HDD ](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309675)

Answer (score 2):

This answer was originally [posted](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309675&p=13423022#post13423022) in an Ubuntu Forums thread [Live-CD won´t detect my HDD](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309675) as mentioned in  [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720244/ubuntu-live-cd-cant-detect-my-hdd-solved#comment1065713_720244).

> In the end all this BIOS tunning didn't played any role on my problem, as [Grahammechanichal suggested](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309675&p=13422130#post13422130) I set my bios back to legacy boot and managed to install using a tool called FixParts. Aparently the problem is related to GPT data.
>
> 1. So the first step was to boot using your USB Stack or CD/DVD and select ***"Try Ubuntu"***.
> 2. After doing that just load terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
> 3. And launch FixParts to fix it...it can correct the problems almost automatically. See [Rod Smith's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343908) for more details.