# default boot device missing or boot failed after destroying GPT data

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt

I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 parallel to Windows 10. I was unable to find any of the partions while installing ubuntu and I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/443535) answer. I tried the steps mentioned by Walid Ammou. I then wanted to make sure nothing went wrong so I quit the ubuntu installation without installing and rebooted my system but I am not able to boot into Windows. I get a message saying `default boot device missing or boot failed`. My hard drive doesn't seem to be in the boot menu.

I will appreciate any help!

**EDIT:**
[This is the output of `sudo parted -l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYOn.jpg)

**EDIT2**
[This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzhFz.jpg)

**EDIT 3:**
[This is the output of `gdsik`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhray.jpg)]

Comment: Boot into Live Ubuntu, then run command `sudo parted -l` and post output into question. Also the make and model of your PC will help.

Comment: @PaulBenson Please see the edit

Comment: You' have a 1000 GB raw, unformatted disk, so nothing is on it. No systems showing. If you had any important data on it I hoped you backed it up first.

Comment: @PaulBenson So i've lost windows? I did back up my data so that's not a concern

Comment: I'm afraid so. If you were lucky to have taken an image of W10 (you should always do that) you can restore it quickly. Otherwise you're looking at a re-install of both systems. Do Windows first.